# Determinate Parcel Neighbors using PYTHON

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1

As you can see in the First picture, I have parcel 220, and i want to determinate the position of each of his neighbor ! So the idea was to calculate the bearing between the centroinde of 220, and the other centroid of neighbors (when the bearing is between [50,150] = North; [150, 250]= East; [250,350]= West ...). So to determinate the neighbors i use the function `arcpy.PolygonNeighbors_analysis (in_features, out_table, {in_fields})`(Picture 2), and at the picture 3, we have a parcels with centroide (X,Y).
So each time i should take

1. (X,Y) of P220 as start Point and (X,Y) of P228 as end point than calculate bearing
2. (X,Y) of P220 as start Point and (X,Y) of P227 as end point, calculate bearing
3. (X,Y) of P220 as start Point and (X,Y) of P226 as end point, calculate bearing
4. than for all the neighbors on the Picture 2

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]
For doing this I used three loop for, and I think it's turning right, but it does it just for the first row, and doesn't move to the newt row!

The code is this:

```
>>> cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Join_Output_12")
>>> cur2 = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Join_Output_12")
>>> cur_t = arcpy.UpdateCursor("tb20_12_2014_")
>>> del row2, Refname__table_neighbor, start_x1, start_y1, end_x1, end_y1, copy_field
>>> for row in cur :  
...     Refname_feature = row.getValue("RefName")
...     for row_t in cur_t :
...         Refname__table_target = row_t.getValue("src_RefName")
...         if(Refname__table_target==Refname_feature):
...             start_x1 = row.getValue("POINT_X")
...             start_y1 = row.getValue("POINT_Y")
...             print Refname_feature
...             print start_x1
...             print start_y1
...             Refname__table_neighbor = row_t.getValue("nbr_RefName")
...             print Refname__table_neighbor
...             for row2 in cur2 :
...                 copy_field = row2.getValue("copy_field")
...                 if (copy_field==Refname__table_neighbor):
...                     end_x1 = row2.getValue("POINT_X")
...                     end_y1 = row2.getValue("POINT_Y")
...                     print copy_field
...                     print end_x1
...                     print end_y1
...     row = cur.next()
```

The result is:

```
1
221408.8543
200288.7235
1
1
221408.8543
200288.7235
```

So I think that the problem comes from for loop!

Now after getting this result, that you can see on the picture 4 (Position off each parcel)
[image: Picture 4]
The result i get was good! But it doesn't respond at 100% to my need, to be more clear let's see the example of parcel 221, it has parcel neighbor 220 at North and also West, but at the table we can see just North, for that i want to canncatenate this result to the result of the function `CalculateAdjacentFields_cartography (in_features, in_field)`
you will tell me why just not to use only this function ? but it's also uncomplete ! look at picture 5 to see the result 
[image: Picture 5]
Let's take the exmaple P220, we can see that it sets just 224, 226 on North, even if there is More !
So the idea is to concatenade the two results to get at last one more complete and reliable result !
But how to do it ? i can't find one logic to combinate them !!

EDIT :
This is an example of complicated relationship, and on the table after what i get as result
[image: Picture 6]
the lin in color, presents Neighbors picked up by the program, and when i looked what a kind of parcels mess, i found is just who is not in touch with the taget parcel (as 164 P2 and 150 in North..)!!
[image: Picture 7]

Comment: Why are you using two update cursors on the same layer?

Comment: beause i want it to point on the firt point (consider as the origin), and look for the other points (th relation ship between this points is shown on the table 2) and get the value of X & Y and consider them as the end points, to draw a last lines, going from the origin point to the other points !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embedded cursors are the worst way to program anything.  Don't do it.  Your code fails because cursors only read one way once.  So the interior cursor has to be completely rebuilt from scratch and started over for every record in the outer cursor.  For every additional record you have to compare in each table the time it takes to compare the two tables grows on basically an exponential growth curve, which should be avoided at all costs if you have anything more than 50 records in each table.

Your cursors also are not da cursors, so they are 10 time slower out of the gate.  Use two completely separate cursor loops.  One to read the data from the sources to two dictionaries and the other to update the features based on matches made to the dictionaries.  Dictionaries are random access structures, cursors are not, and dictionaries are in memory while cursors are not.  So you get about 20 to 100 time better performance with the approach I am recommending.  See my blog on [Turbo Charging Data Manipulation with Python Cursors and Dictionaries](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/11/08/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and-dictionaries).

You are using UpdateCursors but not writing anything to the table.  Why? You need an X and Y field to write to.  You only need one UpdateCursor on one source ever, never two on the same data source.  Define those fields and their names and which table they will reside in.

So study my blog and start over.  You will be glad you did.

Thanks for editing your post with a graphic that explains the source of the tables and the objective of the analysis as well as better tables to work with.  The first step is to add 4 Double fields to the table with the two src_RefName and nbr_RefName fields to hold the XYs of the two centroids from the other table so there is a place to store the results of the updatecursor.  I will call them X_Start, Y_Start, X_End, and Y_End.  Also add another double field for Bearing.  The Bearing calculated below is the trigonometric bearing that begins at due east and goes counter-clockwise, not the navigational bearing that begins at due north and goes clockwise.  If you want the navigational bearing then change the line that reads: updateRow[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlolw.png) = (angle + 360) % 360 to updateRow[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlolw.png) = (90 - angle) % 360.  The bearings association to the compass points are [45-135] = North, [135-225] = West, [225-315] = South, [315-359.9..., 0-45] = East.

Now load the table with the centroid XY into a dictionary.  Then get the two RefName values of each row and fill in the 2 XY coordinates and the bearing double fields.  The third example in my blog can be adapted to do the process.

```
from time import strftime  

print "Start script: " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  

import arcpy  
from math import degrees, atan2

sourceFC = r"C:\Path\SourceFeatureClass"  

sourceFieldsList = ["RefName", "POINT_X", "POINT_Y"]  

# Use list comprehension to build a dictionary from a da SearchCursor  
valueDict = {r[0]:(r[1:]) for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sourceFC, sourceFieldsList)}  

updateFC = r"C:\Path\UpdateFeatureClass"  

updateFieldsList = ["src_RefName", "nbr_RefName", "X_Start", "Y_Start", "X_End", "Y_End", "Bearing"]  

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(updateFC, updateFieldsList) as updateRows:  
    for updateRow in updateRows:  
        # store the src_RefName and nbr_RefName value of the row in a pair of keyValue variables  
        keyValue1 = updateRow[0]  
        keyValue2 = updateRow[1]  
         # verify that the keyValues are in the Dictionary  
        if keyValue1 in valueDict and keyValue2 in valueDict:  
            # transfer the value stored under the keyValues from the dictionary to the updated field.  
            updateRow[2] = valueDict[keyValue1][0]  
            updateRow[3] = valueDict[keyValue1][2]  
            updateRow[4] = valueDict[keyValue2][0]  
            updateRow[5] = valueDict[keyValue2][3]  
            angle = degrees(atan2(valueDict[keyValue1][4] - valueDict[keyValue2][5], valueDict[keyValue1][0] - valueDict[keyValue2][0]))
            updateRow[6] = (angle + 360) % 360
            updateRows.updateRow(updateRow)  

del valueDict  

print "Finished script: " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Edit:

You have extended your question to a different problem about trying to accurately describe the picture using a table of compass directions.  In doing this you are raising a much bigger problem.  Writing a program to evaluate your picture correctly into this table is like trying to [get a group of blind men to agree what an elephant is like when they only experience a small part of it](http://www.jainworld.com/literature/story25.htm).  That is what you are attempting when you program complex realities into simplified generalizations and break it up into separate examinations of small parts.  It is nearly impossible to have blind men operating this way come up with the same description of reality that a sighted person will explain.

Our eyes and brain are amazing at nearly instantly determining what to take in and what to throw out when trying to evaluate the picture you gave, and no program you or I can write can equal it.  However, even for sighted people the complexity of your shapes means that there is no perfect table, since even sighted people can approach your problem from several points of view and come up with different compass direction description tables (I can see several correct answers myself, depending on the methods I adopt).  So at some point you have to be satisfied with the imperfections generalizations always create and the limitations of a chosen methodology.  But that does not mean you are limited to a program that only considers just one methodology.  However, the methodologies should to be applied in a progressively more complex way after less complex approaches prove inadequate.

For example, you have not really evaluated the bearings of your polygons where they touch, you have only evaluated the bearings of your polygon centroids.  This is the part of the elephant your blind men have experienced and currently told you about this elephant.

[image: The Centroid Elephant]

Those centroids may have a poor relationship to the shared edge of your polygons.  A potentially better analysis is to examine the two bearings of the polygon centroids to the centroid that falls on the shared edge of your polygons.  As part of that analysis you probably also must determine which polygon is along the right side of the shared edge and which is along the left side of the shared edge to get the normal angle to the line at the line centroid for each polygon.  This will form another set of angles that could reveal the sufficiency or insufficiency of the centroid bearing you have already examined for describing the relative compass orientations of the two polygons.  Obviously translating this set of angles to equate to what your eyes and mind consider is more challenging, but probably more like what your brain is actually doing.  You could also look at the ends of the shared edge and their normal angles as yet a further way to evaluate the adequacy of the centroid of the shared edge for giving a picture of reality.  Here is a picture of the part of the elephant that this shared edge centroid analysis could paint:

[image: Edge Cenroid Elephant]

If you look at the bearing of the centroid of polygon 224 to the centroid of polygon 220 in the first picture it appears that the bearing relationship should be described as southwesterly.  However, when you look at the picture of the bearings of the centroid of polygon 224 to the centroid of its shared edge with polygon 220, it is clear that the bearing relationship between 224 to 220 from that point of view is more accurately described as a southeasterly bearing relationship.  From different points of view, both are true of this elephant.  The question is, do you only accept one of these answers as true or do you accept both as true?

But what if the two polygons touch in multiple places and share more than one continuous edge?  What do you do then?  The answer is always solve the simplest problems first and then find a way to isolate the set of objects that defy that solution and retest only that set.  That is what makes a good program process efficiently without wasting precious time doing a lot of unnecessary evaluations.

As you can see this problem can go way beyond what a simple post can answer and depending on the importance of this table to your analysis needs, only you can determine how much time you are willing to spend getting the programmatic blind men closer to the reality of the elephant that you, the sighted man, see.  Nonetheless, now you can see that the technique of converting non-random access cursors to random access dictionaries (and now lists inside dictionaries) is essential to make it even possible to evaluate the problem efficiently.

Comment: I saw the examples and the second and third examples can respond to my need, but they are just about 1:1 Matching, while i have me more than 1 as you can see in the picture on top

Comment: There are three basic ways to deal with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.  One is discussed in the blog, where you use a multi-field key to convert a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between tables to a one-to-one relationship.  The second approach loads multiple records associated to one key into a list of tuples.  See the dictionary creation part of this post ( https://geonet.esri.com/thread/118917 ) for an example of that.  The third approach creates multiple dictionaries to traverse the relationship.  One or all of these techniques could be applied to your problem.

Comment: will, i saw all the examples, and i dont know if you understand what i'am trying to do or not, because i can't see like what i'am looking for in you'r examples !

Comment: It is true, I did not write an example that exactly does what you want to do.  However, all the coding components required to do what you need are in the code you have seen in that blog or my other post if it is adapted.  In any case, restart your code borrowing from any example that comes closest and post that.  You have more than enough to get you started.  Then I will help you refine it.  I understand what you want, but I fear the one who does not understand is you.  Where is the fun in my coding it for you and showing I understand, when I can help you do that and make you understand.

Comment: Additionally, there is a flaw in your stated logic and your example shows the flaw.  Your original code did the steps you wanted to do, but returned the same point twice, which is not your objective.  What do you want to do with RefName 105 and copy_field 105?  There are 8 different points tied to that pair of values.  How is any code supposed to know what to do with that?  How can anyone say one is a start and the other is an end?  Additionally, it appears any value of RefName will always be the same as sc_RefName, nbr_RefName and copy_field since RefName and copy_field are always the same.

Comment: If you are actually trying to translate a M:M or 1:M relationship to a 1:1 relationship, you need an insert cursor to expand the number of rows, or many columns of X/Y pairs to create a single row with all of the X/Y values you want to chain.  Your original code does not do either and is  an even worse design as far as performance is concerned if this is the relationship you need to resolve.  You must create a new table to output this relationship.  My code can use an insert cursor to do that, but you need to better define the final output table you want, since this can be handled many ways.

Comment: The more I look at your data, the more irrelevant the second table appears to be.  If you just want to determine the X/Y of the first instance of RefName 105 and the X/Y of the last instance of RefName 105 in Join_Output_12, a single cursor can do that without ever doing any lookup on the second table.  None of your screen shot data shows any reason for using the second table at all.  Also nothing you have said every explains where this data is supposed to end up being stored, which is a crucial piece of information to creating any code that is sensible.  What is the final output of this code?

Comment: Thank you Richard for your interest, and i'am sorry if i said anything wrong. I edit my question trying to answer to your questions (please reread it), and i will as you recommand, start to adapted my code to your example, and and post it again ...

Comment: Now that you have provided a much better explanation of what you are doing I was able to easily adapt my third blog example to do what you now say you want to do.  See my edited post.

Comment: Woow, it's very strong ! i cant treat 10 parcels on 1 second !
thank you very much Richard, but i'll still need you on the second part ! i'am trying to write the code if it doens't work i will post it again, THANK YOU again !

Comment: Richard i edit my question, please check the change

Comment: IF you want more results first of all I would never just fill in a direction field, I would calculate the actual bearing into table 4.  Then as you create table 5, you can determine if a candidate fits North and West in the case of 221, i.e., the bearing is more North, but since there is no other candidate for West and this bearing is enough to the Northwest to fit, use it to fill the West column also.  For 220, use a Search cursor to create a list of all North objects to create a delimited list in RefName_N, or fill in  RefName_N1,N2,N3 columns.  Cursor can do it. You try from my post example

Comment: thank you Richard for this explanation, it's very important, but i thinhk it will take a lot of time  to prepare an other code, i promise you to try to be more effecient, and logical, i just should start at the beginning...

Comment: hi Richard, i read back your proposition with more of attention, and i see that what make a work difficulte, is that not having a regular form of parcel, and not always a touching one (complexity of shape asyou mentionned above)! so your logic will give result such i got ! and to be more clear (to avoid to full in elephant example), when the parcel is described as southwesterly i just consider it in SOUTH, at final i get (NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST) and about the resultof the table 4, i concatenate this table ("Refname_NE", "Refname_N", "Refname_NW") on one table "NORTH" the same for South...

Comment: So i think the real problem is how to do with thhe parcel when they don't touch ! whn we have sometimes track betwen them !!!! if you want i can publish the last results i attain (if that will help)

Comment: I edited my question....

Comment: If this table is for the outlined parcel, why does north show 148 and 155 touching and why does south show 65 touching?  They do not touch.  Why doesn't west show 157 and S8970/08 touching?  They do touch.  What about 101 and 102 that are interior?  What code or process did you use to get the latest table?  Anyway, the roads are a separate problem that you should isolate and solve separately, then integrate that new table with the table you have created.  You must create a polygon for every road, find out what parcels touch each road, then buffer test just those parcels against each other.

Comment: This thread is getting out of hand.  Start a new thread and outline your latest approach and then describe what rules and problems you still want to solve.  Also, before you do any of this analysis you should be using topology to determine if gaps exist between the outlined parcel and parcels 157 and S8970/08 and fix them.  Otherwise you have to start over after fixing those issues.  Besides, I deserve about 5 up votes from you for this thread alone and can't get any more without a new thread.

Comment: Hi Richard i made a new thread as you asked http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130643/algorithm-to-determinate-neighbors-position-n-s-e-w-of-parcels