# Algorithm to determinate neighbor's position (N S E W) of parcels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

After my first publicaation [Determinate Parcel Neighbors using PYTHON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127510/determinate-parcel-neighbors-using-python/127529#127529)
Where i was looking for a faster way to calculate parcel neighbors and position, and after succeeding that, but the result was not full and reliable at 100%, view of complexity of your shapes, so Mr. Richard Fairhurst proposed me to start a new tread and search for a new algorith more efficient and giving more complete and reliable results !

[image]

So me i suggest as algorithm to calculate centroide of each polygon, then make a multiple projections of this point on the intersection between two polygons (target and neighbor polygon)

[image]

After calculate a bearing of each line, then associate bearings  to the compass points are [45-135] = North, [135-225] = West, [225-315] = South, [315-359.9..., 0-45] = East....

So My Question are :

- what do you think about the algorithm is it strong or can stack...
- Do you have any way or idea how  to make a projections explained before ?

for the rest i made it before as you can see on the last publication mentionned before !

I'am using Arcgis 10.1, and Python language.

Answer (score 2):

For the example shown, polygon 185P1 would obviously qualify as South of polygon 187.  Hard to tell if it would also qualify as East, but the bearings from those lines seem like they would provide enough information to determine whether or not the neighbor should also be considered East.  Clearly polygon 185P would not be considered North or West of polygon 187 is you tested the bearings of the lines shown, so that seems to fit what you want.  In any case, for the example it seems that testing those bearings would provide the best answer for determining the set of relative compass directions that describe the relationship of polygon 187 to polygon 185P1.  So this method seems sound.

In your previous post you indicated that you wanted to include polygons that did not directly touch as neighbors if there was no polygon between them.  Is that still true or not?  Is that what you mean by "Do you have any way or idea how to make a projections explained before?"?

Do you want polygon 185P1 to consider 185P2 to be a neighbor or not?  They seem close enough together to use a buffering tolerance as a test.  Do you want polygon 187 to consider polygon T18188/44 a neighbor or not?  They are not very close and would create more challenges to evaluate based on a buffer tolerance.  If you want these polygon pairs to be treated as neighbors than the challenges would be how to first identify the set of polygons to test for this condition and then how to identify which points to use as representing the neighboring shared edge that are not blocked by another polygon.